# Issue with Left Outer Join in Julia DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, join, julia

This one has me stumped.

Im trying to join two dataframes in Julia but I get this wierd 'nothing' error. This works on a different machine so Im thinking it could be package problems. I Pkg.rm() everything and re-install but no go.

Julia v1.2

```
using PyCall;
using DataFrames;
using CSV;
using Statistics;
using StatsBase;
using Random;
using Plots;
using Dates;
using Missings;
using RollingFunctions;
# using Indicators;
using Pandas;
using GLM;
using Impute;


a = DataFrames.DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3], y = ["a", "b", "c"])

b = DataFrames.DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3, 4], z = ["d", "e", "f", "g"])

join(a, b, on=:x, kind =:left)
```

yields

```
ArgumentError: `nothing` should not be printed; use `show`, `repr`, or custom output instead.

Stacktrace:
 [1] print(::Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Nothing) at ./show.jl:587
 [2] print_to_string(::String, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./strings/io.jl:129
 [3] string at ./strings/io.jl:168 [inlined]
 [4] #join#543(::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Nothing, ::Tuple{Bool,Bool}, ::typeof(join), ::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at /Users/username/.julia/packages/DataFrames/3ZmR2/src/deprecated.jl:298
 [5] (::getfield(Base, Symbol("#kw##join")))(::NamedTuple{(:on, :kind),Tuple{Symbol,Symbol}}, ::typeof(join), ::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at ./none:0
 [6] top-level scope at In[15]:4
```

kind=:inner works fine but :left, :right, and :outer don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem caused by the way Julia 1.2 prints `nothing` (i.e. that it errors when trying to print it). If you would switch to Julia 1.4.1 the problem will disappear.

However, I can see you are on DataFrames.jl 0.21. In this version `join` function is deprecated. You should use `innerjoin`, `leftjoin`, `rightjoin`, `outerjoin`, etc. functions. Then all will work also on Julia 1.2, e.g.:

```
julia> leftjoin(a, b, on=:x)
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ y      │ z       │
│     │ Int64 │ String │ String? │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ a      │ d       │
│ 2   │ 2     │ b      │ e       │
│ 3   │ 3     │ c      │ f       │
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that they finally fixed that `nothing` thing!